# How to create a custom column in folders

Tags: 22.04, directory, customization

Is there a way to permanently create a custom column in folders?

I want to create a column that specifies some properties of a file

Answer (score 0):

Open Files and select the hamburger menu (3 parallel lines icon) selecting Preferences from the menu then List Columns tab.

You can select additional options from there.

[image]

Comment: I want to create my own column, not ones that already exist